# AutoLayout problems in iPhone5

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, autolayout

I have a Xcode 4.5.2 Project
I have a story board with with four UIViews. 
Autolayout is Set to ON in the StoryBoard
Deployment is iOS 6

**I want the letterbox to appear on top and bottom when running on iPhone 5 and not have my views resized when running on a iPhone5**

When I run my app in iPhone5 - I do not see the letterBox - the UIViews are automatically stretched (incorrectly)

When I run the App on iPhone 4 - Everything is as expected.

Why does the letterbox not show as I would expect?

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you want your app to behave on iPhone 5 the way older apps do -- automatically letterboxed by the OS to 3.5-inch screen dimensions, just don't include a Default-568h@2x.png in your app. However, Apple expects new apps submitted to the App Store to support 4-inch screens, so you might not get very far with this strategy if you're expecting to distribute your app that way.

If you want to "support" iPhone 5 (and iPod touch 5th generation) screens, but keep most of your UI at older screen sizes... well, your users may not like it (and the App Store reviewers might not either), but it's possible using Auto Layout. The catch is that the root view in your window's (or rather, your view controller's) view hierarchy is always automatically resized to fit the screen -- but there's no saying that has to be the main container for your actual UI content.

1. In IB, with the editor in 3.5 inch screen mode, drop a new UIView into your view controller's root view. It should automatically size to fill the screen (460 points high).
2. Add a **Pin > Height** constraint so the view stays 460 points high no matter how its superview gets resized.
3. Add an **Align > Vertical Center in Container** constraint so the view stays centered when the height of its superview changes.
4. Put all of your UI inside this view.

Now you'll get white bars (change the color of the root view if you like) above and below your UI when on iPhone 5.

Note this only works as long as your UI doesn't rotate to landscape. I don't think you can do this kind of artificial letterboxing for both orientations using only one set of constraints, so if you want to support rotation you'll need to [respond to an orientation change](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW9) by switching out constraints programmatically -- pin height and center vertically in portrait, pin width and center horizontally in landscape.

Comment: Is it a better practice to use Spring and Struts (they never seem to do what you want) or use two storyboards - one for iPhone_3_5_inch and another one for iPhone_4Inch

With regards to AutoLayout - I understand that is only possible in iOS6.  If I want to support both iOS 5 & iOS6 and also want to support 3.5 & 4 inch - Is two storyboards my only choice.

Comment: You can do this with springs & struts, too: Make height fixed, and both top & bottom spaces flexible. You'll still need to change your `autoresizingMask` programmatically if you want to support rotation, though.

Comment: But my understanding is that auto layout is not supported in iOS 5.  So your only choose is two storyboards if you want to support 3.5 and 4 screens without letter boxing - is that not correct?

Comment: Auto Layout is not supported in iOS 5, but springs & struts are still supported in iOS 6; unless you really want to use Auto Layout on iOS 6 you can just use the old stuff and not need to keep two storyboards.